# Android: How to determine which fragment the view with focus resides in

Tags: android

I am new to Android and I haven't been able to figure this one out yet.

I have a fragment which is reused multiple times in my app.  I need to identify which fragment contains the view with focus when a menu item is clicked so I can update an EditText view in that fragment.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

In your container(parent) activity, you can check whether that fragment is null:

```
MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myfragment_id);

if(fragment != null)
{
  //this fragment is used currently
}
```

or you can put a variable ,set that variable according to current fragment.

Comment: I really don't understand how this solves my problem.  I need to know which fragment has focus when a menu item is clicked.  All fragments are of the same type.

Comment: Could you please send some source to make your question more clear? I may missunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

in your parent activity:

```
    private TextView mFocusedText = null;

    public void textViewGotFocus(TextView tv) {
      if(tv != null) mFocusedText = tv;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      if(mFocusedText != null) mFocusedText.setText(item.getTitle());
    }
```

in your fragments ad a focus listener on a item your choice or multiples and call

```
    getActivity().textViewGotFocus(myFragmentTextView);
```

it isnt tested but it should work this way

good luck